# JavaScript not called from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, square-connect

i have created html form and loading in UIWebView

```
NSString *pageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform\"></script></head><body><h1>My Payment Form</h1><form id=\"form\"><label>First Name</label><input id=\"sq-Fname\" /><br><label>Last Name</label><input id=\"sq-Lname\"/><br><label>Payment Amount</label><input id=\"sq-Amount\"/><br><label>Credit Card</label><div id=\"sq-card-number\"></div><label>CVV</label><div id=\"sq-cvv\"></div><label>Expiration Date</label><div id=\"sq-expiration-date\"></div><label>Postal Code</label><div id=\"sq-postal-code\"></div><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"cardNonce\" name=\"nonce\"/><input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"submitButtonClick(event)\" id=\"btnSubmit\"/></form><div id=\"errors\"></div></body></html>"];
[_webView loadHTMLString:pageString baseURL:nil];
_webView.delegate = self;
```

and in WebView Delegate

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
        NSString *javaScript=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [_wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
}
```

static form load successfully in UIWebView but in HTML code some fields should load from javaScript api but javascript file is not running.

Comment: You can try `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];` instead of `[_wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];`

Comment: @arunjos007 tried but no success..